# what is error in problom?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Is not error

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: '<h1>InlineTemplate</h1>',
styles: ['h1{color:red;}']})
```

But after Enter error

```
@Component({
selector: '
app-root',
template: '
<h1>InlineTemplate</h1>',
styles: ['h1{color:red;}']})
```

I don't know error
Is TypeScript 
tools sublineText3

Comment: Post the code and error here, as text. Also, describe what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: I think for multi-line you have to use backtick ( ` ) instead of single quote ( ' )

Comment: Use ` (backtick) instead of '(single quotes) in your "template"

Answer (score 0):

Use ` (backtick) instead of '(single quotes) in your "selector" and "template"